# How can I shorten this code snippet?

Tags: c#

I'm sorry for the vague title, I think you really have to see the snippet to know what I mean:

```
float[] foo = new float[3];
FillFoos(foo);
return foo;
```

I'd like to have that in one line (I use this snippet very often). How would that be possible?

Comment: Note: Of course, I can't edit FillFoos to simply return a float[].

Comment: Why you can't? just return updated input values.

Comment: And your reason for a one liner is ?

Comment: It's a wrapper over C++ DLL code. I have access to FillFoos only, I can't edit it. My reason for a one liner is that I have this code structure over 100 times in my code.

Comment: if you haven't already, check out this [stack-exchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review"). I think you'll find it useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, you could make a generic function that allocates an array and uses a supplied delegate to fill it:

```
 public static T[] AllocAndFill<T>(Action<T[]> fillAction, int count)
 {
      T[] array = new T[count];
      fillAction(array);
      return array;
 }
```

And use it like this do:

```
 var result =  AllocAndFill<float>(FillFoos,3);
```

Comment: That's the most logical solution, unfortunately it won't work in my context, as Action has many more possible signatures. Accepted nonetheless.

Comment: Well, you can make function overloads that allow you to call fill functions with extra parameters, or use lambda syntax to write an action inline. I can elaborate if you're interested...

Comment: No need to elaborate, I understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't alter the `FillFoos` function, then your snippet is as short as it can be.

You could, of course, do this:

```
float[] foo = new float[3]; FillFoos(foo); return foo;
```

But that's still three statements and is fairly tough to read.

Answer (score 3):

You could just create a function:

```
public float[] GetFoos()
{
    float[] foo = new float[3];
    FillFoos(foo);
    return foo;
}
```

EDIT: If you need to change the size of the array and the method to populate the array then you could do this:

```
public float[] GetFoos(int count, Action<float[]> populateAction)
{
    float[] items = (float[])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(float), count);
    populateAction(items);
    return items;
}
```

then you can call it like this:

```
float[] items = GetFoos(3, FillFoos);
```

You can even make it generic:

```
public T[] GetFoos<T>(int count, Action<T[]> populateAction)
{
    T[] items = (T[])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T), count);
    populateAction(items);
    return items;
}
```

Comment: It's not always foo, not always 3 floats, and not always FillFoos. It's different functions that fill float arrays.

Comment: You can make the method Generic, and accept the array length as an argument.

Comment: And add a delegate for FillFoos' replacement? This can't work, FillFoos is not always 1 parameter long, sadly. :/

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in another method.

```
T[] GetObjects<T>(int length) 
{
    T[] foo = new T[length]; 
    FillFoos(foo); 
    return foo; 
}
```

Now, instead of using that snippet everywhere, just call `GetObjects<Foo>(3)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change `FillFoos`, then you could write some kind of helper method (perhaps as an extension method on whatever object contains `FillFoos`).

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static float[] SuperFoo(this FooObject foo, float[] floats)
    {
        foo.FillFoos(floats);
        return floats;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
return fooObj.SuperFoo(new float[3]);
```